# Calculate distance from current Latitude and Longitude with different Latitude and Longitude in one kilometer

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem I think but I can not find the ideal solution. I am storing different restaurant locations latitude and longitude in Mysql table. I want to find a restaurant around 1 km radial distance from current location of user using latitude and longitude so how to do this. I have to show all restaurants which are in 1 km radius from user current location latitude and longitude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select restaurant table entries within a certain distance from current location using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104816/select-restaurant-table-entries-within-a-certain-distance-from-current-location)

Comment: no it not solve my problem I need all restaurant which are under 1 km without duplicate

Comment: Without table structure, example data, correct user case (you forgot to mention you needed unique restaurants within 1 km did you forget annymore?) and expected results we know even less then you, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), this question is unclear like it is and will be most likely voteclosed.

Comment: I mean all the restaurant which are under 1km from user current location

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula of distances using longitude and latitude

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)

c = 2 * atan2( √a, √(1−a) )

d = R * c
//Where φ represent the latitudes, and λ represent the longitudes.
```

Reference: https://www.sisense.com/blog/latitude-longitude-distance-calculation-explained/

Also you can check this page for using javascript.
https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score -2):

Remember that latitude and longitude originally are writed on degrees, I think you first need to know how much distance represents 1º, on some books and websites it says that 1º is about 111km depending how near is the spot from the equator line, so (more or less):

```
1º  - 111km, also 1º equals 60'
then 1' should be 1.85km, and 1' equals 60"
then 1" is more or less 0.03km 
so 32.4324" is about 1km
```

Now... basically you need to now the limits of a square based on the initial location, for this just add/substract 32.4324" to latitude and longitude, so give it a try.. lets go to las vegas (use google maps)

```
36.1699412,-115.1398296
```

This locations is on a sexagesimal  notation son lets convert 32.4324".. its simply... just divide it on 3600 and that is 0.009009009, this is the value you must add/subtract to/from latitude/longitude

```
north bound, after add: 36.1789502
south bound, after substract: 36.1609322
east bound, after add: -115.1308206
west bound, after substract: -115.1488386
```

now on gmaps try to locate these bounds for ex (north bound: 36.1789502,-115.1398296) you will see is just above original location, you can also measure distance from original location up to 1km and that is more or less near to the north bound you just calculated.

so now, just query your database and filter it where latitude is between north bound(36.1609322) and south bound(36.1789502), and also longitude is between west bound(-115.1488386) and east bound(-115.1308206) and that should do the work. So the magic is just to add/substract 0.009009009 to any location point.

Comment: Why not just go with a the standard approach for calculating distance on a sphere

Comment: @Strawberry i'm not sure about that, but anyways explain us how to solve the problem, just keep in mind the goal, it is to get a list of restaurants stored on database that are in 1km radius from an initial location.